# Changing Background Color, CreateJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, createjs

I want to change the background color of the stage/canvas upon a certain input, to enunciate a change in the mode that the program is in. Therefore I would like to change the canvas to black when in the different mode and then back to white when the mode is inactive. The background defaults to white.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="1500">Alternative Content</canvas>
```

but I imagine I would want to change it with respect to what is in my init function.

```
                var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
            canvas.setAttribute('tabindex','0');
            canvas.focus();
            stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
```

Any ideas how I can change the background color with regards to an input?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the color using JavaScript to set the CSS style.

```
// Change it to red
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";

// Change it to the value of a text input
canvas.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("myTextInput").value;
```

There is currently no way to do this directly with EaselJS or the Stage.

Hope that helps.